# Can I manipulate output stream this way?

Tags: c++

I was trying to print an integer in binary format using output stream manipulators in C++ but I was unsuccessful in doing so. 
I tried using the following code to manipulate the base.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int binary, gray;
    cin >> binary;
    cout << std::setbase(2) << (binary >> 1);
}
```

But I guess only decimal, hexadecimal and octal bases are supported in this manipulator.
Is there any way I can print an integer in binary format using manipulators in `iomanip` header?

Answer (score 0):

Use [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/) i.e.

```
cout << bitset<16>(10).toString() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::setbase` only supports bases of 8, 10, or 16. You can use `std::bitset<N>` to print out the binary representation yourself however:

```
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::bitset<16>(0x1F); // 0000 0000 0001 1111
}
```

Comment: In fact, "Values of base other than 8, 10, or 16 reset basefield to zero, which corresponds to decimal output and prefix-dependent input.", see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setbase)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bitset>
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int i=13;
    std::bitset<8> bit (i);
    std::cout<<bit.to_string();

    return 0;
}
```

result:

> 00001101

---

```
cout<<bitset<8>(0xd).to_string();
```

gives the same